# Django dump : models don't validate

Tags: django, django-models, dump, django-database

When I try to dump the data of my model in Django with this instruction :

```
python manage.py dumpdata app> temp_data.json
```

It gives the following error :

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
asset.authpermission: "codename": CharField cannot have a "max_length" greater than 255 when using "unique=True".
asset.djangocontenttype: "app_label": CharField cannot have a "max_length" greater than 255 when using "unique=True".
asset.djangocontenttype: "model": CharField cannot have a "max_length" greater than 255 when using "unique=True".
```

The thing is that these tables are auto-generated by django. Plus I just checked in the database (mysql) and the fields are varchar(100).

What's wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those tables are generated by a `manage.py inspectdb` right? Then you don't need to include django's own models into the actual generated models. Just remove any model starting with `auth`, `django`, `admin` and `site`.

Just include the corresponding contrib apps to the INSTALLED_APPS setting and voila, no more errors.

Answer (score 3):

Django is attempting to validate your schema against what the database backend will allow before it lets you dump. The issue is this:

> CharField cannot have a "max_length" greater than 255 when using "unique=True".

The problem you're experiencing is this: `CharField` translates to `VARCHAR` in SQL - if you have `max_length` that translates to `VARCHAR(X)` where `X`is whatever you set the maximum length to.

MySQL, for tables that aren't MyISAM, won't index (hash) for searching any data longer than `255` characters in a `CharField`. This also rules out `TextField` which translates to SQL `TEXT`.

The MySQL docs on indexing [are fairly comprehensive](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html). The [`CREATE INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) documentation gets you to the heart of the issue:

> FULLTEXT indexes are supported only for MyISAM tables and can include only CHAR, VARCHAR, and TEXT columns. Indexing always happens over the entire column; column prefix indexing is not supported and any prefix length is ignored if specified. See Section 11.9, “Full-Text Search Functions”, for details of operation.

In other words, unless you're using MyISAM as your storage format, you can't do this.

There is an argument either way as to whether this is a design fault or not; on the one hand, you could argue that really, if you need to index such a huge bucket of data as a full pile of text, you really need to think about that more carefully. On the other hand, you could argue that 255 is an arbitrary choice for a limit. Why 255 and not 300? Or 200? I d

I've just hit upon this issue myself. The solution is to ask whether `unique=True` is actually required, then decide if `max_length` really does need to be that long. In my case we were storing sha512 output, which is 128 chars long, so I just resized the fields appropriately.

However, if you do need unique long data, you can enforce this yourself by overriding a models `save()` method. What you actually want to do is override the `full_clean` method, which is called by `django.forms.*` to validate your model's data against the schema, then have an overridden `save` method call that. That way, the uniqueness constraint occurs whether you save directly or call `is_valid()` on a form.

The other option is to switch to MyISAM, or use postgres.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing is that I did not create the tables which have problems, django did automatically. I don't use them manually anywhere. And I noticed that it does not validate the models since I put my app in the installed_apps, before everything was executing correctly ..

Comment: @Johanna until you add an app to installed_apps, django doesn't try to validate any models it might have - installed_apps tells it where to look to do that. Have you run syncdb since installing this new app? I wouldn't expect it to work because the backend should complain - this will complain even if you're not using that area of code yet, since django will validate all model schemas (the sql it actually uses) with the database backend(s).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I'm kenw to Django. I was confused because when I ran the server it said "validating models...". But it's good now, saverio's answer worked fine